# How to avoid automatic renaming of sub signature parameters in visual basic 6

Tags: ide, vb6

In Visual basic 6, i declare a sub like this:

```
Private Sub test1(ByRef XmlFooOutput As String)
  ...
End Sub
```

Aafter that, I declare another sub like the following one:

```
Private Sub test2(ByRef xmlFooOutput As String)
  ...
End Sub
```

Automagically, the first method is transformed in:

```
Private Sub test1(ByVal xmlFooOutput As String)
   ...
End Sub
```

So the XmlFooOutput parameter is transformed in xmlFooOutput.

This is a pretty dangerous feature because methods like those could be mapped to different XSL presentation files that read XML values through Xpath.
So when test1 parameter is renamed, XSL bound to test1 method goes broken because Xpath points to XmlFooOuput but the correct value is now in xmlFooOutput.

Is it possible to remove this weird feature?
I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 (SP6).

This question has some duplicates:

- [Stop Visual Basic 6 from changing my casing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064858/stop-visual-basic-6-from-changing-my-casing)
- [VB6 Editor changing case of variable names!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248760/vb6-editor-changing-case-of-variable-names)

From what I see, there's no practical solution to disable this Intellisense evil feature.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this behavior in VB6 SP5.  Is this code in a form, module or class?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. VB6 is not case sensitive, so XmlFooOuput is the same as xmlFooOuput.  If you want to ensure variables have different names in VB6, I believe you actually have to have differences other than the character case.

Comment: @Heather
This behaviour is in both form and module.Have not tried in class.
@Smoore
Confused for what?Do you think it is not weird?

Comment: @systempuntoout That is very weird.  Does it still do the same thing if you take care to type the second instance of `XmlFooOutput` in the exact same case as the first?

Comment: No, it does not.They stay equal with first letter upper case.

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248760/vb6-editor-changing-case-of-variable-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case of variable names and other identifiers makes absolutely no difference to the language - VB6 is **case-insensitive**.

I agree it can be annoying when the IDE changes the case of identifiers automatically. There is already a detailed discussion of possible workarounds [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248760/vb6-editor-changing-case-of-variable-names).

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Visual Basic that probably originates back in QuickBasic, as has been pointed out stems from case insensitivity in names.

I tried the example of the OP and VB6 changes the declaration of `test1()` as described.

Its not possible to remove this feature - you will have to find another way round this.

Comment: Actually we are living with this problem since 2005.
Sometimes it happens that somebody in our team checkout some module, modify it adding another sub with different case, messing the other subs of the module.
This is a subtle and awful bug that can be a pita to discover when you are developing because the renaming is done silently without warning.

Comment: You need to find a way round this: Check your version control commits. Run your tests before committing.  Best of all find a way of removing this requirement from your code.