# Odd behaviour of casing of a control name in vb6 code

Tags: ide, vb6

I have a label control on a form named **lblTotal**

During my last commit to the repository I was surprised to see this form's name on the modified list.

When I looked through the code I saw that all occurrances of this control's name were now **lbltotal**, (ie Small t).

The control's name itself was **lblTotal** in the properties window.

Further when I used ctrl-F with case matching to find **lbltotal** it would only find one as instantly all other occurrances would revert to **lblTotal**.
So it seems that at some moment after the IDE records some event in the code window it gets around to making the casing conform to the control's name.

What I don't understand is how this happened in the first place without a change to the control's name?
Can someone explain how?

PS After I wrote the above I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248760/vb6-editor-changing-case-of-variable-names). Interestingly I also had a string variable that's name had its casing changed  during the same commit and I assumed I must have changed it myself but now, having read the above I think it's because the same variable name was present in a different scope.
However there is no other occurrance of **lbltotal** anywhere else in the project.

PPS **lblTotal** is actually **lblTotal(0)** and many more copies are loaded during runtime, so a lot of the code references are **lbltotal(x1).Caption** etc. I don't know if this makes any difference.

Finally has anyone ever seen vb6 change the casing of string literals by itself? (Please God no!!)
Actually this last point is what causes me the most unease about this experience as in TOO many places in the codebase string literals are used in conditional clauses.

Comment: VB6 does this to us at work also; we just got used to it, and no longer look for casing changes between versions.  The link you supplied is a very good description of the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, it's reassuring to note that people don't view this as more than a nuisance. I don't think my example is exactly the same behaviour as that in the link. Firstly this is a control rather than a variable and secondly there is nothing anywhere else in the project with the same name.

Comment: I've seen this too. Very annoying. Just make sure you ignore case when diff'ing

Comment: Good point, I haven't one that before.

Comment: You might be interested in the discussion here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248760/vb6-editor-changing-case-of-variable-names which I think covers your point.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the behaviour mentioned, VB6 will also re-case variable names that happen to occur in any of the COM interfaces your program references, which means that if you reference a new library, or change their order, you're in for even more fun.

At one time I even wrote a small program that "right-cased" VB6 source code from a dictionary of names ; the main drawback to that is you have to run it before each source commit.

But I think the answer from wqw here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078018/108753 is probably the best solution to the problem I've seen, because he has quantified and exploited the behaviour of the IDE to solve the problem.

At least it's not VB3 - VB3 re-cases every variable in any files you have loaded into memory to *what you last typed*. Which makes you a lot more precise about typing case in variable names....